# How to find when a user has subscribed to the product for first time?

Tags: sql

Provide a sql query(any engine) to compute the first time a user has subscribed to the product.

Table: subscribers

```
Month     Year  User
January   2016  ZandraDilnot
January   2016  AlfonseMeans
January   2017  KandyChiandotto
February  2017  AlfonseMeans
February  2017  SusanRowan
March     2017  AlfonseMeans
March     2017  ZandraDilnot
March     2017  CrystalPoindexter
```

I tried the use of Where and group by combo to come up with logic but can't find the right query to so!

select month, year, user 
from subscribers
where (Need to check for min year)
group by user

Expected Output

```
Month     Year  User
January   2016  ZandraDilnot
January   2016  AlfonseMeans
January   2017  KandyChiandotto
February  2017  SusanRowan
March     2017  CrystalPoindexter
... ... ...
```

Comment: Is column `Month` as text - `January`, `February`, ...?

Comment: Its not specific to any db, you can consider  the month section as Datetime data type.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```sql
SELECT User, MIN(Year),MIN(Month) FROM subscribers GROUP BY User
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do with a CTE ... not ... I added an extra column with the Month as a number just so it's easier to sort without having to convert it inline.

```
create table #Test (m1 varchar(100) , m2 smallint ,  y int, u varchar(100));
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('January  ',1,2016,'ZandraDilnot      '       )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('January  ',1,2016,'AlfonseMeans      '       )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('January  ',1,2017,'KandyChiandotto   '   )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('February ',2,2017,'AlfonseMeans      '       )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('February ',2,2017,'SusanRowan        '   )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('March    ',3,2017,'AlfonseMeans      '       )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('March    ',3,2017,'ZandraDilnot      '       )
insert into #Test (m1 , m2 , y , u) values ('March    ',3,2017,'CrystalPoindexter '   )

;

with cte1 AS 
(
select * 
    ,  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY u ORDER BY m2 , y ) AS R
From #test
)
select * 
From cte1 where R = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to merge the first two columns and create a date field. Then the following query:

select user, min(date) from tbl group by user

should work.